# Can we say "In the beginning" in other situations than just in Bible?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

After googling "`define: "in the beginning"`", we often see a quote in Bible

***In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.***

Normally we use "**at the beginning**", ex "*at the beginning of the lesson / movie...*"

My question is:
What does "**In the beginning**" mean?

Can we say "**In the beginning**" in other situations than just in Bible?

Comment: See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20389/at-the-beginning-or-in-the-beginning

Comment: Did you look up [the meaning of the word "beginning"?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beginning)  After you look it up, what do you think "in the beginning" might mean?